# Determine plane equations that go through coordinate axis and are perpendicular to a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

I can't seem to figure this out, so I hope someone could help me.

I need to determine the equations of the planes that go through the coordinate axis and which are perpendicular to a given plane (Q): $3x-4y+5z-12=0$.

Comment: About which axis do you say? $x$, $y$, $z$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\vec{n}(a,b,c)$ be a normal of the plane.

Thus, $3a-4b+5c=0$ and if you mean the $x$-axis then $a=0$ and we got the equation
$$5y+4z=0.$$

Comment: It asks for the equations based on all three axis, I think. And how did you get to that last form of "5y + 4z = 0"? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: We have no a plane, which goes through all axis. It's impossible. About your answer: Because $(0,5,4)(3,-4,5)=0.$

Comment: I think it talks about 3 different planes here. Each one going through an axis. Sorry if my translation is lacking.

Comment: If so,  the rest equations for you.